# Error in svd(xs) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, data-mining, outliers

```
p<-c(1,2,3,4)
sign2(cbind(p))$wfinal01
# [1] 1 1 1 1

p<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
sign2(cbind(p))$wfinal01
# Error in svd(xs) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Could anyone please explain what is happening above while trying to use the `sign2` function of R from `mvoutlier` package?

Comment: Is linked to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21424647/3250126 
However, don't have an answer yet