# R return error "Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'"

Tags: r, logistic-regression, ordinal

I was running order logistics regression but it returned error like `"Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'"`. Can you guys help me on this?
My data set is like below. And the regression is `regression = polr(rank ~ ratings + reviewNum + activeUsers + Downloads, data = Sample,Hess = TRUE)`

```
 date rank travel  ratings reviewNum activeUsers Downloads

1   2/1/2017    1      N 4.928571        14      117684      5541
90  
2/1/2017   11      N 1.000000         1       26056      1946
179 

2/1/2017   10      N 4.786667        75       55507      7600
268 

2/1/2017    6      N 2.600000        10      130150      7154
446 

2/1/2017    4      Y 1.000000         1       19167      2369
535 

2/1/2017    3      N 4.833333        12       87341      6274
624 

2/1/2017    7      N 4.273810        84      193104     14214
>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: [This is the first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423375/r-svd-function-infinite-or-missing-values-in-x) link that comes up in a search of the error. My guess would be that one of your variables is not behaving well.